# Count all files in sub directories and sort by count

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code to get the count of files in each folder in a parent folder, but I would then like to sort these by the count and possibly then output to a file as well, maybe csv.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Name $(Get-ChildItem $_ | Measure-Object).Count}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go about this a little differently.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object FullName,@{Name = 'FileCount'; Expression = { ($_.GetFiles()).Count }}
```

This will get the count of files in each directory object produced by `Get-ChildItem`. It will output custom objects like below:

```
FullName                                 FileCount
--------                                 ---------
C:\temp\PowerShell File Read Performance 12
C:\temp\SO_09-26-20                      35
C:\temp\test4                            24264
C:\temp\TestFiles3                       0
C:\temp\Test_10-30-20                    3
C:\temp\VSCode-Data-Backup_07-07-20      0
C:\temp\VSCode-Data-Backup_07-07-20_2    0
```

If you want to send to a csv file:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object FullName,@{Name = 'FileCount'; Expression = { ($_.GetFiles()).Count }} |
Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\DirectoryCounts.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to count immediate sub-files AND directories you can add those counts like:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Directory | 
Select-Object FullName,@{Name = 'SubCount'; Expression = { ($_.GetFiles()).Count + ($_.GetDirectories()).Count }} |
Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\DirectoryCounts.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Obviously I don't know exactly what you'd like to see in the CSV file but this should demonstrate the point sufficiently.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. If you feel comfortable please accept the answer.  Thanks.